# Angular Material checkbox and weird spacing

Tags: html, css, angularjs, checkbox, angular-material

I have a panel where I put angular material checkbox. Because the panel is black I set the background color of the checkbox to white to indicate to the user that it's there. However, there is some spacing added to the right of the checkbox which I can't seem to get rid of. Anyone know how to fix this ? Setting Padding to 0 doesn't work

[image]

```
 <div id="chartWrapper-{{$index}}" style="position: relative">
         <div id="chartTopPanel-{{$index}}"
          style="position: absolute; display: none; left:0; top:0; height: 15%; width: 100%; opacity: 1; background-color: darkslategrey; z-index: 100;">
                   <md-checkbox id="chartSelect-{{$index}}" style="
                   position: absolute;  margin:10px; background-color: white; padding-right: 0" >
                   </md-checkbox>
         </div>             
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This whitespace is not due to the checkbox icon but due to its label

I think you should try this css rule.

```
md-checkbox ._md-label
{
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution:

```
.my-checkbox {
  margin: 10px !important; /* Not really required */
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/BzxAZV)

Answer (score 0):

Do not add background to whole checkbox component. rather just background to its container (checkbox area)

```
md-checkbox ._md-container {
    background: #fff;
}
```

you can use CSS class to modify this solution.